# Getting this Error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebeca for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Line 1037: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebeca for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_vector.h)
0xbebebebebebebeca: note: pointer points here

SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:1046:9

```
vector<int> spiralOrder(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {

        vector<int>ans;

        int row = matrix.size();
        int col = matrix[0].size();
        int top=0; 
        int bottom=row-1; 
        int left=0;
        int right=col-1;

        while(top<=bottom && left<=right){
            for(int j = left; j<=right; j++){
                ans.push_back(matrix[top][j]);
                top++;
            }
            for(int i = top; i<=bottom; i++){
                ans.push_back(matrix[i][right]);
                right--;
            }

            if(top <= bottom){
                for(int j = right; j>=left; j--){
                    ans.push_back(matrix[bottom][j]);
                    bottom--;
                }
            }
            if(left <= right){
                for(int i = bottom; i>=top; i--){
                    ans.push_back(matrix[i][left]);
                    left++;
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: Please create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: A side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: You are most likely indexing outside a vector. My main suspects would be `left` and `bottom`.

Comment: Clearly you are indexing outside the bounds of your vector. I would add `top` and `right` to the list of suspects. See code like this every day of the week and it's almost always an array/vector indexing issue.

Comment: If you print your indices you will see that you are nowhere near a spiral, and if the matrix is wider that it is tall you will index outside the height. See e.g. [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/891747834dc9c27e).